# Estimating of point in the density of bimodal distribution

Tags: r, distributions, estimation, optimization, density-function

I'm trying to estimate a specific point in a bimodal distributions, It's the point that I indicated in my picture with the A.
[image]

As example we can generate a mixture of guassian and then try to determinate the point A(x,f(x)).

This problem is I think a problem of optimization and estimation. My question is, though, how would I go about that in detail? Maybe I'm just missing a good tutorial somehow.

Comment: Are you talking about a sample of $x$'s to which you're trying to find a local minimum of a density, or is this a set of observations of (possibly noisy) pairs, $(x,f(x))$? A mix of gaussians would be able to locate a local minimum of the fit in either case, but the exact estimate of that location may be somewhat sensitive to the gaussian assumption. An alternative would be to smooth the data using kernels (KDEs in the second of the two cases I mentioned). Another possibility is to use log-splines (log-spline density estimation in the second case).

Comment: @Glen_b I believe the solution would be robust to the distribution assumption and/or the kernel shape, provided it is symmetric.  It may even be fairly robust to the choice of kernel width.  Regardless, we do need clarification concerning the nature of the data.

Comment: I am trying to find a local minimum of a density : the coordinates of this local minimum (xA.f(xA))